# flex 4 tree control not updating

Tags: apache-flex, tree, arraycollection

I'm using the MX Tree control in Flex 4.6. Its data provider is a nested ArrayCollection. The way the control works is that when a tree node is expanded the event is bubbled up to another component which detect the event and fetches data from the server and updates the ArrayCollection (i.e. the ArrayCollection of the clicked branch). But the updated data doesn't show up in the tree until I close the particular branch and expand it again.

E.g.

- + Folder 1
- + Folder 2
- + Folder 3

Initially the Folder 1 children is an empty ArrayCollection when the user expands Folder 1 data is fetched from the backend and added to the children ArrayCollection. But this doesn't show the children under the Folder 1. If I close Folder 1 and open it again it shows up. I thought when data was added to the ArrayCollection it should update the display. Can some one please let me know what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the following has worked to notify the Tree control that its list needs to be redrawn:

- arrayCollection.refresh();
- tree.invalidateList();

Comment: But I thought the Tree class would listen to the ArrayCollection class change events and redraw itself when a change occurred without the invalidateList() being explicitly called. Isn't that why we use ArrayCollection class?

Comment: I've found sometimes that I need to call invalidateList() on a Tree in certain cases. You say that your ArrayCollection is nested? How is it structured, an ArrayCollection of ArrayCollections? Perhaps the Tree will be notified correctly if you replace the nested ArrayCollection rather than add to it.

Comment: Each item in the ArrayCollection has a children object that is an ArrayCollection in turn. The parent ArrayCollection is part of my model and the tree is in a UI component. A controller component bind the UI to the ArrayCollection in the model. When the user opens a tree node I detect the event in the UI and send it to a controller component which updates the children. This should update the Tree automatically since the tree is supposed to be listening to the CollectionChange Event. This is the part that is not working. I will try to add a code outline soon that may make it even more clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to the problem. When any of the children ArrayCollection classes are updated I need to call itemupdated on the main ArrayCollection class. This updates the view correctly. So in the above example if the user clicks on Folder 2, the event gets propagated to a model that adds data to the children arraycollection of Folder 2, once this is done I should call itemupdated on my main ArrayCollection with the updated item as Folder 2, this updated the Tree View correctly.